# How to wrap words in single quotes using sed script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am curious how can I do the following thing with sed: I need to wrap certain two words in single quotes in each line. For example, the following text:

I did it like this:

```
cat file |sed "s/[^ ][^ ]*/'&'/g"
```

result:

```
'the-first-word' '-firstPrameter' 'value' '-secondParameter' 'value' '-thirdParameter' 'value' '-fourthParameter' 'value'
```

But it is wrapping every word.

It should be like this, skip the first word and wrap only parameter and value:

```
the-first-word '-firstPrameter value' '-secondParameter value' '-thirdParameter value' '-fourthParameter value'
```

Comment: Do all of the parameter tags start with `-`?

Comment: `cat file |sed` is a Useless Use Of Cat.  Instead, just give the filename to sed as the last argument.  And can you explain why you need to do this?  Maybe there is a totally different solution.

Comment: now it wraps '-'. 
'the'-'first-word' '-'firstPrameter' 'value' '-'secondParameter' 'value' '-'thirdParameter' 'value' '-'fourthParameter' 'value'

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the first word is at the start of the line. Thus, if we quote all words that have a space in front of them, then we will quote all but the first:

```
sed "s/ \([^ ]\+\)/ '\\1'/g" file
the-first-word '-firstPrameter' 'value' '-secondParameter' 'value' '-thirdParameter' 'value' '-fourthParameter' 'value'
```

If your `sed` supports the `-r` flag (GNU), then we can remove some of those backslashes:

```
sed -r "s/ ([^ ]+)/ '\\1'/g" file
```

On Mac OSX, replace `-r` with `-E`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s/ \([^ ]* [^ ]*\)/ '\\1'/g" file



$cat file.txt
the-first-word -firstPrameter value -secondParameter value -thirdParameter value -fourthParameter value

$sed "s/ \([^ ]* [^ ]*\)/ '\\1'/g" file.txt
the-first-word '-firstPrameter value' '-secondParameter value' '-thirdParameter value' '-fourthParameter value'
```